# Axios not attaching headers after killing app React-Native

Tags: react-native, cookies, header, axios, config

```html
 AsyncStorage.getItem('@cookie').then((token)=>{
          console.log('Toekn' , token);
          const Kit = axios.create({
            headers:{
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Set-Cookie' : token
            },
            withCredentials: true
          });

          Kit.interceptors.request.use(
            config => {
            console.log(
            `%c ${JSON.stringify(config)}`,
            'color: #0086b3; font-weight: bold',config,);
            return config;
            },error => Promise.reject(error),
            );
            // Intercept
          
          Kit.post('http://myadmin.com/Patient/CaseCalender')
                .then(res => {
                  console.log('data',res)
                    if(res.data.length >0 ){
                      this.setState({isLoading: false});
                      
                      var _data = JSON.parse(res.data);
                      this.setState({
                        data: _data
                      });
                    }
                    else{
                      this.setState({isLoading: false});
                    }
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response,'check error');
                this.setState({isLoading: false});
              });
  

         })
```

I'm using axios for calling my apis in react-native my code works fine before if kill the application, After killing application axios not attaching cookie header in its config.
Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: You need to add some example code therefore, we can help you @Qamber :)

Comment: @FreakyCoder please check it i have added my code.

Comment: Same code works fine when i login to app and use application frequently, But when i kill my application axios gives me 404 error. I have checked its config before and after config remain same like cookie and url and other things are exact same. Please help me i'm stuck in this issue for a while .